# How to Bind to a methods in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, binding

I am trying to bind `monthCalendar` date to `MyDate` property and avoid circular invocation but monthCalendar doesn't have `get;set;` properties for current selected date. It has only method `SetDate(DateTime date);` for setting new date and events `monthCalendar1_DateChanged`, `monthCalendar1_DateSelected` for returning current selected date. How to bind them to `MyDate` property? In WPF method is available as a resource so you can bind to its results. How to achieve that in `System.Windows.Forms`?

```
    private static readonly object _dateLock = new object();

    private DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MyDate
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_dateLock)
            {         
                //updating control
                return myDate;                    
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (_dateLock)
            {         
                //getting date from control
                myDate = value;   
                SetDate(new DateTime(myDate.Ticks));
            }
        }
    }

    //Fired when date changed
    private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //update source
        lock (_dateLock)
        {         
            MyDate = new DateTime(e.Start.Ticks);   
        }         
    }


    private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if bottom region with current date clicked
        if (IsCurrentDateClikced())
        {             
            //update source    
            lock (_dateLock)
            {              
               MyDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);   ;
            }
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add these to the setter

```
        set
        {
            lock (_dateLock)
            {
                // Setting date 
                myDate = value;
                monthCalendar1.TodayDate = myDate;
                monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = myDate;
                monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = myDate;

            }
        }
```

the calendar reacts as expected. Circular triggering didn't happen here, maybe because once they have the same date the `Changed` event doesn't get triggered as there is no change?

I had to comment out the `if (IsCurrentDateClikced())` , though. Does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by adding notification.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
{
     if (PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
}

private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    //update source
    lock (_dateLock)
    {         
        MyDate = new DateTime(e.Start.Ticks);  
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDate"); 
    }         
}


private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if bottom region with current date clicked
    if (IsCurrentDateClikced())
    {             
        //update source    
        lock (_dateLock)
        {              
           MyDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
           NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDate");
        }
    }       
}
```